# Data extraction problem based on upper case words

Tags: text-processing, scripting, csv-simple

I have a data file in the following format:

**source.dat** (*Example for illustration purposes*.)

```
ALBANIA Duck 1000
BELGIUM CHARLEROI Donald Duck 10234
CYPRUS J. Mickey 567
```

I'm looking for a Linux script (Bash, perl, whatever) to extract the info into `csv` format, with the given rules:

- **1st** field in `csv` contains only the entire words which are in **uppercase**
- **3rd** field in `csv` contains the **last input field** (number)
- **2nd** field in `csv` contains the **remaining** middle part

So the expected output should be:

**output.csv**

```
ALBANIA,Duck,1000
BELGIUM CHARLEROI,Donald Duck,10234
CYPRUS J.,Mickey,567
```

Comment: @Costas, can you post as an answer, with some comments?

Comment: @Costas The last part of your command should read : `\1,\2/'`

Comment: Sure. I misread positions of 3rd and 2nd fields from the task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Portably:

```
sed 's/\([^[:lower:]]*\) \(.*\) /\1,\2,/' < source.dat > output.csv
```

Comment: Fail if line have trailing spaces. Easy fixed by indicate last symbol like `[^0-9]`

Comment: @Costas, true, but in the dataset there's no trailing space.

Comment: @Costas, if there's a trailing space, one may argue the last field is after that trailing space and is empty.

Answer (score 2):

If do directly as asked

```
sed -r 's/([[:upper:] .]+)\s+(.*)\s+([0-9]+)\s*$/\1,\2,\3/' file
```

As we can see the field1 is remain on the place, so we can simplify script

```
sed -r 's/\s+(\w*[[:lower:]].*)\s+([0-9]+)\s*$/,\1,\2/' file
```

even

```
sed -r 's/\s+(\w*[[:lower:]].*[^0-9])\s+/,\1,/' file
```